# How to disable "To sync this notebook, sign in to OneNote" banner on OneNote 2016 (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

Every time I start OneNote, I get this annoying banner message (see picture below):

"To sync this notebook, sign in to OneNote".

Is there a way to disable this message and get OneNote to simply sync the notebooks quietly? If I go to File > View Sync Status and press "Sync Now" it syncs without problems and the message disappears. Or if I just click on the banner it does the same. I do not understand why I am getting this message and why OneNote does not sync automatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You said OneNote 2016, so I am guessing this is the desktop app.
Well it is difficult to understand the issuing without knowing a few things,
Have you checked if,

1. You are using an O365 subscription and have a valid license ?
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16
   or [Depending on x86 or x64]
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16
   cscript OSPP.VBS /dstatus
2. If yes, do you see your account in the top right corner in One-note.
3. Under Account --> Connected Services, do you see that one-note is connect to your tenants one-drive with the same account you are using.
4. What do you see in other office applications (for e.g. excel) under File -- > Account --> User information. You should ideally see the same account.